# "insecure content" in Chrome for bookmarlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, bookmarklet

I developed a small [bookmarklet](http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/), and it worked fine till the chrome last update.

Now it runs "insecure content" when it's clicked while on facebook and it doesn't even start on twitter.

I'd like to know hoe to avoid "insecure content" and blocking by chrome.

Here's the code:

**bookmarklet**

```
if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src","http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js");
    script_tag.onload = function() { $.getScript('http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/scrolltv.js',function(){main();}); };
    script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded')  $.getScript('http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/scrolltv.js',function(){main();});
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    $.getScript('http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/scrolltv.js',function(){
        main();
    });
}
```

**injected js**

```
var status = 0;
$bottom = 100;
$position = 0;
function scrollTV() {
    if ( ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 500 ) >= $position ) {
        $position = $position + 50;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$bottom}, 2500, 'linear', function() { 
           $bottom = $bottom + 100;
           scrollTV();
        });
    } else {
        $('html, body').stop(true);
        $('#style-scroll, #soundtrack, #atransp').remove();
        $(document).fullScreen(false);
        $('#soundtrack')[0].pause();
        status = 0;
    }
};
function start() {
    if (status == 0) {
        status = 1;
        function start2() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#soundtrack')[0].play();
                $('#loading-scroll, #blackscreen').remove();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:1}, 0);
                scrollTV();
            }, 1000);        
        }
        $('#title-scroll').remove();
        if (!($.browser.mozilla)) {
            $('<div id="loading-scroll" class="text-small-scroll" >Loading</div>').appendTo('#blackscreen');
        } else {
            $('<div id="loading-scroll" class="text-small-scroll" ><img src="http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/loading.png" /></div>').appendTo('#blackscreen');
        }
        if (!($.browser.mozilla)) { $(document).fullScreen(true); };
        $('#soundtrack')[0].addEventListener('oncanplay', start2(), false); 
    } else {
        status = 0;
        $('#soundtrack')[0].pause();
        $('#soundtrack, #style-scroll, #atransp').remove();
        $('html, body').stop(true);
        $(document).fullScreen(false);   
    }
}
function main() {
    if (!$('#style-scroll').length) {
        $('<script src="http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/jquery.fullscreen-min.js"> </script>').appendTo('head');
        style = "<style id=\"style-scroll\"> @font-face { font-family: 'AmericanPurpose'; src: url('http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/font/american_purpose_casual_02-webfont.eot'); src: url('http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/font/american_purpose_casual_02-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/font/american_purpose_casual_02-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/font/american_purpose_casual_02-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/font/american_purpose_casual_02-webfont.svg#AmericanPurposeCasual02Rg') format('svg'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; } body { overflow:hidden !important; } div#transpscreen, div#blackscreen  { position:fixed; top: 0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; z-index:9999;} div#blackscreen {background-color: black; z-index:9990} div#title-scroll, div#loading-scroll { width:100%; text-align:center; margin-top:200px; color: white; } div#loading-scroll { margin-top: 300px; } .title-scroll { font-family: 'AmericanPurpose'; font-size: 80px; line-height:50px; color: white; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; } .text-small-scroll { font-family: 'AmericanPurpose'; font-weight:normal; font-size: 19px; line-height: 20px; margin-top:10px; }</style>";
        $(style).appendTo('head');
        $('<a href="#" onclick="start()" id="atransp"><div id="transpscreen"></div></a>').appendTo('body');
        if (!($.browser.mozilla)) { 
            $('<div id="blackscreen"><div id="title-scroll" class="title-scroll">ScrollTV<br/><span class="text-small-scroll">Click to play</span></div></div>').appendTo('body');
        } else {
            $('<div id="blackscreen"><div id="title-scroll" class="title-scroll"><img src="http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/title-firefox.png" /></div></div>').appendTo('body');
        }
        $('<audio id="soundtrack" loop preload="auto" autobuffer><source src="http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/soundtrack.mp3" /><source src="http://www.silviolorusso.com/scrolltv/soundtrack.ogg" /></audio>').appendTo('body');
    }
};
```

suggestions?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change all of your URLs to HTTPS URLs.

Comment: if i simply change http to https it doesn't work. should i do anything else?

Comment: :( my server doesn't allow it. is there any space online where i can temporarely put them?

Comment: Many cloud providers and webhosts allow shared SSL certificates using their own domain names.  I know that AppHarbor does.